# Idea of using LLMs to help communicate ideas in math

Tags: proofs, terminology

What do you guys think about the ideas presented in this short text: https://github.com/yougetyourmanwww/AI-for-math/blob/main/AI.md

The text is about how LLMs like chatGPT can be used for when doing math. I've never seen anyone with the same opinions as me on that topic, so I'd like some opinions on the ideas.

TLDR: LLMs can be used to help communicate math ideas, for example improve the wording in your informal proof or convert the text in a research paper to simpler text. Really the point is that the text generation ability of LLMs can be useful when doing math.

Answer (score 1):

If people find it helpful, that's fine. The author of a text is still responsible for the final version, whether it was aided by an LLM or not.

I have some quibbles with the specific examples in the linked article (e.g. changing "rigorous" to "strict" veers a bit from what the authors want to say) but that may be beside the point. One can (and should) proofread and edit the output of the LLM before finalizing the document, and errors like that are easy to catch.

One downside to keep in mind: there is value in learning to write clearly on one's own. Learning to communicate clearly helps one learn to think clearly. So I would not support students using something like this as they learn to write proofs.